# Primefaces p:datatable sortBy not working properly

Tags: html, primefaces, primefaces-datatable

I have pre-made views displayed on my website. The data query is done via Hibernate from a DB2 database and is displayed with JSF. The whole thing runs on a local JBoss server.

This is the logical bean behind the HTML:

```
@Named(value = "vb")
@ViewScoped
public class ViewBean implements Serializable {

@Inject
private ViewHandler vh;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
}

public List<PortView> getPVList() {
    return vh.getPortViewList();
}
```

The `ViewHandler vh` retrieves the List of the view(s) coming from the respective entity. (see below)

```
@Stateless
public class ViewHandler {

public List<PortView> getPortViewList() {
    List<PortView> pvlist = em.createQuery("SELECT v FROM PortView v", PortView.class).getResultList();
    return pvlist;
}
```

Here you see the p:datatable in my html:

```
<html>
<h:body>
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable var="portview" value="#{vb.PVList}"
        resizableColumns="true" stickyHeader="true"
        stickyTopAt=".layout-topbar"
        style="margin-left:10%; margin-right:10%; font-family: verdana">

        <p:column style="width: 0px" sortable="false" />
        <p:column headerText="Instance" sortBy="#{portview.instance}"
            style="font-family: verdana; text-align:left">
            <h:outputText value="#{portview.instance}" />
        </p:column>

        [more columns]

    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**Problem**: Each single column cannot be sorted, the content is always random. What should I do to solve this?

Comment: You can put `sortBy` right on the Datatable itselt and that is the "default sort" when the table is rendered.

Comment: @Melloware you mean like: `<:p:datatable [...] sortBy="vb.PVList" />` ?

Comment: No see the sortBy on the Datatable docs: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/components/datatable?id=datatable It would be `sortBy=#{portview.instance}` if you wanted the table sorted by default by the instance column.

Comment: @Melloware Thanks, it works exactly as expected! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately @Melloware was able to answer my question: You simply add `sortBy="#{var.property}"` to the `p:dataTable` attribute.

For documentation, see [here](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/components/datatable?id=datatable).